# Balancing Transformation of Linear Time Invariant Systems

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I've been experimenting with linear time invariant systems. In particular I've been playing around with the concept of balanced truncation. All the resources I've found only explain how to do balanced truncation in the case that the Gramian matrices are positive definite (i.e. full rank). But I'm trying to work on a case where the Gramian matrices are only positive semidefinite. Does anyone know what to do in situations like this?

Comment: Have you already looked at the Kalman decomposition?

Comment: Nope, don't know what that is. I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.